# Generate numbers randomly from a set?

Tags: matlab, random

In MATLAB, I have a set of `P` numbers. I would like to generate a random array of size `N` from this set.

For the sake of example, let say I have the set `{1, 4}`. Let say I would like to generate an array of size `5` (e.g., `[1 1 4 1 4]`).

What I did is this: I generated the following array using `randi`.

```
N = 5;
v = randi([1 4],[1 N]);
```

The problem is that I got a random array which contains values in `1:4` and not in `{1, 4}`.
I can simply do this but I need a better way.

```
for i = 1:length(v)
    if v(i) ~= 1 || v(i) ~= 4
       v(i) = 1; % or v(i) = 4
    end
end
```

I think I am missing a simple hint here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `datasample`,

`y = datasample(data,k)` returns `k` observations sampled uniformly at random, with replacement, from the data in `data`.

```
a = [1,4];
datasample(a,5)
```

Depending on the usage, you might consider using,

```
datasample(unique(a),5)
```

Comment: `randsample` is a similar alternative

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have the Statistics Toolbox (which contains the `datasample` function), you can use [`randi`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html):

```
N = 5; %// desired number of samples
data = [1 4]; %// data values
sample = data(randi(numel(data),1,N));
```

And if you use a very old version of Matlab that doesn't have `randi`, you can employ [`rand`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html):

```
sample = data(ceil(numel(data)*rand(1,N)));
```

Comment: I would use `floor(rand*n+1)`, since `rand` can return 0. I think 1 is excluded. Though this method yields a (very small) bias — it’s not a fair die.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Can it? According to the command-line help and to the online [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html), it returns values from the open interval (0,1). That means both `floor` and `ceil` will yield a very small bias; probably not important in practice anyway

Comment: Oh, I didn’t realize it was an open interval. I always assumed the half-open interval. :)  The bias comes from elsewhere, though. See here: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?54619 — It turns out `randi` is biased as well, so there is no way of doing it correctly in MATLAB...

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the pointer. I saw that question and answer (which you recently linked in some other answer), but I hadn't thought it affected `randi`. Has this been reported to Mathworks?

Comment: Yes, I submitted a bug report there too.