# Randomly number selector from a given list of numbers

Tags: matlab, random, matlab-guide

I have given list of numbers,

```
x=[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6];
non_zero=find(x);
```

I want Matlab to randomly select anyone among elements of 'non_zero' at a time. I searched online but there is no such function available to provide my required results.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function `randi` to randomly select an integer from the set of valid indices.

```
x=[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6];
non_zero=find(x);

index = randi(numel(non_zero));
number = x(non_zero(index))
```

Or, perhaps a bit more clear, first make a copy of `x`, remove the zero elements from this copy, and then select a random integer from the range `[1 numel(x_nz)]`.

```
x=[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6];
x_nz = x; 
x_nz(x == 0) = 0;

index = randi(numel(x_nz));
number = x_nz(index)
```

To ensure that you do not get the same sequence each time, first call `rng('shuffle')` to set the seed for random number generation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered `randsample` or `datasample`?

```
x = [1 4 3 2 6 5];        
randsample(x,1,'true')    % samples one element from x randomly
randsample(x,2,'true')    % two samples

datasample(x,1)

% Dealing with the nonzero condition
y = [1 2 3 0 0 7 4 5];
k = 2;                    % number of samples
randsample(y(y>0),k,'true')

datasample(y(y>0),k)
```

---

After posting this answer, I found [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27022985/8239061) from @Rashid (linked by @ChrisLuengo). He also suggests considering if `datasample(unique(y(y>0),k)` is appropriate.

Comment: You mean you found the top answer in the duplicate I had linked yesterday? :p

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, what am I supposed to do?  I hadn't checked out your link until after I'd posted my answer.  Should I just make it a community wiki?

Comment: Nah, don’t worry. It’s just a bit of wasted effort.